# HTML styling Help

Tags: html

I need help in HTML styling

here is the case:

```
<div id="hidden" style="display: none;">
<label>URL:</label>
<input type="text" name="url" size="50"/><br/>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Update"/> <br/>
</div>
<input type="button" id="button1" value ="Get Info" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = '';" size="25"/>
```

as we can see all the elements inside

```
<div></div>
```

will be displayed on clicking button1(they will hidden initially).When all the fields appear the another button inside div(button2) is unaligned to button1.

What i want is when i click button1 both button1 and button2 should be aligned..

how can i do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="hidden" style="display: none;">
<label>URL:</label>
<input type="text" name="url" size="50"/><br/>
</div>
<input type="button" id="button1" value ="Get Info" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display =     '';document.getElementById('button2').style.display=''" size="25"/>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Update" style="display:none"/>
```

If you want the two buttons next to each other, but the second one can only be displayed upon clicking the other button, then you'll need to include script to show the button onclick.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "aligned"? Are they supposed to be aligned horizontally, that-is, they should appear on the same line? If so, you need to remove your `<br />` tags that force line-breaks, and set the display of your div not to blank, but to inline (as divs are displayed as block by default):

```
<div id="hidden" style="display: none;">
    <label>URL:</label>
    <input type="text" name="url" size="50"/>
    <input type="button" id="button2" value="Update"/>
</div>
<input type="button" id="button1" value ="Get Info" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = 'inline';" size="25" />
```

This produces the following when you click on the "Get Info" button:

[image: Screen shot of the horizontally-aligned result]

Note that the text input, update and get info are all on one line!

If you want them all to appear left-aligned, the code that you provided looked just fine when I tested it. Upon clicking the get info button, I get a display that looks like this:

```
[INPUT "URL" AREA]
[Update Button]
[Get Info]
```

If you aren't trying to get your display horizontally aligned or left-aligned, then what type of alignment are you looking for? Can you provide a diagram or screen shot if this is not the answer you're looking for?

Comment: i was looking for horizontal align ..answer of @Ek0nomik is what i was looking for..

Answer (score 1):

I generally agree with what Kiley mentioned a moment ago.  If you must maintain that exact structure and want the buttons horizontally aligned, adding `float:left;` styles to the `<div></div>` and to `button1` would solve your issue.

```
<div id="hidden" style="display:none; float:left;">
<label>Url:</label>
<input type="text" name="url" size="50" />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Update" />
</div>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Get Info" onClick="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = '';" style="float:left;" size="25" />
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

They shouldn't be unaligned, there's probably an style on that div.

try this css

```
#hidden {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```